# how to replace ajax.ActionLink add with ajax.ActionLink remove once the user adds an item?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Im working on MVC 4 project and I want to dynamically replace the add action link with the remove action link once a user adds that specific item to their item list? is this possible using jQuery?

heres my view

```
@model mBooksAdmin.Models.Outlet`<tr class="even">
<td>
    @Model.OutletName
</td>
<td>
    @Model.Address1
</td>
<td>
    @Model.Address2
</td>
<td>
    @Model.City
</td>
<td>
    @Model.State
</td>
<td>
    @Model.Zip
</td>
<td>
    @Model.Country
</td>
<td>
    @Model.Banner
</td>
<td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "Add", "Outlet", new { id = @Model.OutletID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResults", Confirm = "Are you sure you want to Add " + @Model.OutletName + " ?" }, null)
</td>
```

`

Comment: Yes, you can override the success event.  I will post some code momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

See this post which shows how you can use the default OnSuccess() and OnFailure() methods of the MVC Ajax methods:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(ajaxContent) {
        // in chrome, click F12 and go to console to see what's inside...
        console.log(ajaxContent);
    }
</script>
```

Ref.  [ASP.NET MVC3 AJAX.BeginForm AjaxOptions OnSuccess OnFailure Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143299/asp-net-mvc3-ajax-beginform-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-onfailure-problem)

Comment: but wouldn't any ajax call fire this event?

Comment: Yes but a different object would be passed each time.  From the `ajaxContent` you should be able to get the ID which you passed to the controller.  Then, you can do something with that ID.